# How do I convert an array of arrays to a 1D array

Tags: javascript

```
[
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
]
```

I have an array inside an array, and I am trying to get rid of the parent array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let input = [
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
];

let result = input.map(item => item[0]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good catch. Stack Overflowing on my IPhone. Lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) as `let result = input.flat()`.

> The **flat()** method creates a new array with all sub-array elements concatenated into it recursively up to the specified depth.

Alternatively you can also use `concat` to merge arrays like `result = [].concat.apply([], input);`

```js
let input = [
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda6s4",
    "resource": "three",
    "code": 3,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
];

let result = input.flat();
console.log(result);

result = [].concat.apply([], input);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `.concat()`

```js
let input = [
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
];
var newArr = [];


for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
  newArr = newArr.concat(input[i]);
}

console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the new [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method (Chrome 69+, Firefox 62+ and Safari 12+).

```js
const arr = [
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
];

const flattenedArr = arr.flat();
console.log(flattenedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

use spread operator. 
for example,

```js
const parentArray = [
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a07c7791b4083fbda644",
    "resource": "one",
    "code": 1,
    "__v": 0
  }],
  [{
    "_id": "5be9a0877791b4083fbda645",
    "resource": "two",
    "code": 2,
    "__v": 0
  }]
];

const immediateChildArray = [...parentArray];

console.log(immediateChildArray);
```

All the best pal.

Comment: `[...array]`  is essentially a noop(and is only useful for creating a shalllow copy of `array`). As such, this solution doesn't work.

Comment: oh yea that's so true @AyushGupta. Maybe I will suggest using map or Array.from then. ciao.

Answer (score 0):

For this input you can also use following code

```
const d = JSON.stringify(input).replace(/\},|\}],/g, '}|').split('|').map(d=> d.replace(/\[|\]/g, '')).map(d=>JSON.parse(d));

Here I use the following step:
1. Conver Object to String,
2. Then replace "}," and "}]," symbol with '}|'
3. Then split by "|", so now I have each object individually as a string.
4. Now I remove other symbols like "[" and "]" from the string.
5. And last I convert each string to Object. And now we have array of objects.
```